# How to place normally closed switch in Visio

Tags: switches

Today I was making a simple diagram in Visio Pro, when I needed to use a normally closed switch. Is there a way to place it? I haven't been able to find it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the switch and you should be able to select switch state open or closed. If you want to label the contacts I think you need to edit the switch symbol or place text near the symbol.

Comment: Do I use Make Contact or SPST as a basic switch? I don't like the big circles on SPST but Make Contact doesn't have the Show closed circuit button. I'm really confused on which one you use for a normal switch. I'm using Visio 2016

Comment: I always used the SPST switch from Electrical Engineering › Switches and Relays category.

Answer (score 0):

Visio is NOT a schematic editor. As such I bet there are hundreds of electronic symbols it does not have. You have to draw your own.
I use ORCAD and even there I regularly have to draw my own symbols.

Comment: I agree, but sometimes you need to use what you have.

Comment: ... or what everyone else in your organisation has.

Comment: And then there are dozens of decent dedicated online tools.